how to change the package name in android studio
I am trying to upload a new release to google play but it is giving an error Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.app.myapp. Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: $(applicationId).provider. Now I am trying to change the package name in AndroidManifest.xml from package="com.example.myapp" to package="com.app.myapp" as soon as I change that, errors show in the activity tags in manifest file
Class referenced in the manifest, com.app.myapp.MainActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries Unresolved class 'MainActivity'  and it suggests me to create class MainActivity.
How can I change the package name of the app? thanks.

Does this answer your question? Rename package in Android Studio
